# Modal Pop Up Extender and Update Panels

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

The ModalPopUpExtender makes a reference to "hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" - this is a hidden button on the UI and it does not seem to be used anywhere except in the code shown below.

The target for the modal pop up is the PANEL pnlNew, then why is the TagetControlID assigned to ID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"? Just trying to understand this wiring...thanks!

The  CancelControlID="btHiddenOK"  is not used anywhere on the modal pop up control (there is a separate cancel button on the modal pop (please see the SAVE and the CANCEL button in the update panel right below the comment ..LOT OF CODE.....so i tried to remove the attribute CancelControlID="btHiddenOK" - which resulted in the modal pop up being disabled? I was wondering that if the btHiddenOK is not even used on the modal pop up - removing it should not have any effect, but that does not appear to be the case?

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" style="display:none"/>

     <asp:Panel ID="pnlNew" 
                   runat="server"               
                   DefaultButton="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"
                   style="width: 575px;">                  
               <!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->    
               <div class="shadowAreaBig" >  
                      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ModalPopupControls" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
                            <ContentTemplate>                                   
                             <div class="shadowContainer  shadowContainerNew" >



                                <!--    LOT OF CODE       --> 




   <div class="buttonsNew">
                            <span class="buttonSave">
                                <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Create new user" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/css/images/buttonSave2.png" OnClick="btOK_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return validateControls();" TabIndex="110" style='display: none;' /> 
                                <img style="border-width:0px;cursor: default;" alt="Create new user" src="../css/images/buttonSave2_disabled.png" tabindex="110" id="ImageButton1_Disabled" >
                            </span>
                            <span class="buttonCancel"/>
                                <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Cancel" ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/css/images/buttonCancel.png" OnClientClick="cancel();return false;" TabIndex="111"/>     
                            </span>
                           </div>    


                              </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>                   
               </div> 
                             <!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->      
            <p class="clearFloat"></p>       
        </asp:Panel>
        </div>   

        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender          
            ID="CreateMPExtender" 
            runat="server"         
            TargetControlID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"
            PopupControlID="pnlNew"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            DropShadow="false" 
            BehaviorID="ModalPopupBehavior"       
            OkControlID="btHiddenOK"
            OnOkScript="ok()"
            OnCancelScript="hideModalPopup()"      
            RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
            PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlNewSRO"
            CancelControlID="btHiddenOK"       
            />  

          <asp:Button ID="btHiddenOK" runat="server" Style="visibility:none" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, and use, the modal dialogs:

PopupControlID tells the modal dialog which panel (or dialog) to display when the user click the button assigned to show it.  As such, it is required

TargetControlID tells the modal dialog which button to assign its "Open" event.  In other words, when this button is clicked, show the dialog.  Although this is required, it does not need to be made visible.  You can hide this button and open the dialog in either javascript  or in the server code behind

BackgroundCssClass just a CSS class the defines how the background should look.  this is optional

BehaviorID is not required (and i find usually causes strange behaviors).  this describes what javascript to fire when the dialog opens.

OkControlId is optional.  It is the button that the modal dialog will use for its OK button event

Both scripts are optional and are just use to tell the contorl what javascript function to call.

PopupDragHandleControlID is optional.  you can tell what panel to use for  the "Drag" event.

As I mentioned above, the CancelControlID and OkControlID are optional.  If you are seeing that this disables the modal extender, or causes other problems, try also removing BehaviorID.  If this does not help, let me know.